# How can I tell how big a TV season download will be in iTunes?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, itunes, itunes-store

I have a pretty full internal hard drive, so I'd like to know how big a TV season download will be before I purchase it in the iTunes store.  Following the purchase, I'm planning to move it to a USB hard drive.

You can check download sizes easily for movies (shows up as something like "1.60 GB" under the buy button), but I don't see anything similar on the TV season page.  Am I overlooking something?

I have iTunes 9.0.3, the newest version at the moment.

Comment: have you tried checking download sizes for each episode in the season?

Comment: Yep, and no info was provided.  I just went ahead and started downloading after I figured I'd have enough space on the external drive and could move them over as they downloaded.  For other's reference, each ~45 minute episode at 640x480 was around 550 MB a piece.  26 episodes * 550 MB = around 14.5 GB.

Comment: feel free to post that as an answer below.  you can't accept an answer to your own question immediately (wait a couple of days), but finding your own answers and sharing them is very much encouraged here.

Comment: I'd posted it as a comment because it didn't really seem like a "real" answer, but will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Per comments:**

I just went ahead and started downloading after I figured I'd have enough space on the external drive and could move them over as they downloaded. For other's reference, each ~45 minute episode at 640x480 was around 550 MB a piece. 26 episodes * 550 MB = around 14.5 GB.